# Is there a way to force an XMLHttpRequest to use HTTP/1.1?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http2, http-1.1

I have a server endpoint that supports both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP2. For testing purposes, I want to try downloading content from the endpoint with both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP2 connections, possibly at the same time.

When I request data from the endpoint with an XMLHttpRequest, it automatically uses HTTP2, without me including the `Connection: Upgrade` header.

Is there a way to force an XMLHttpRequest to use HTTP/1.1 for the underlying TCP connection? What about other protocols, such as Quic or SPDY?

Comment: The browser decides which protocol it wants to use as an implementation detail of the `XmlHttpRequest` object. You can't force a particular choice from inside your script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

From Remy Lebeau's comment:

> The browser decides which protocol it wants to use as an implementation detail of the XmlHttpRequest object. You can't force a particular choice from inside your script.

Answer (score 1):

You could use IE10.  It does not support HTTP/2 and will use HTTP/1.1.  If you have IE11 installed, you can force it to behave like IE10 using its F12 developer tools interface.