# Can axios be configured to use HTTP/1.1?

Tags: javascript, axios, http-1.1, quic

We use axios to query an API and as long as QUIC is enabled in Chrome the request fails, because the server does not support it.

Can axios be configured to use only HTTP/1.1 for a certain request?

Comment: Chrome shouldn't be using QUIC if the server doesn't advertise support for it. It sounds like the server is misconfigured here.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the answer:

[Is there a way to force an XMLHttpRequest to use HTTP/1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56675358/is-there-a-way-to-force-an-xmlhttprequest-to-use-http-1-1)

axios uses XmlHttpRequest as adapter for POST requests and it is not possible to control which protocol the browser chooses to use.