# Is there a way to request a server to not answer request with Transfer-Encoding: chunked on XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, request-headers, transfer-encoding

Is there a way to request a server to not answer request with Transfer-Encoding: chunked on XMLHttpRequest?

Like passing a value in the header during the request?

In another SO question they said one can use HTTP 1.0, I don't know if this is possible with XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell the HTTP server to not send chunked encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31969990/how-to-tell-the-http-server-to-not-send-chunked-encoding)

Comment: See [Is there a way to force an XMLHttpRequest to use HTTP/1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56675358/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, OK, but is there another way to set it to not send chunked?

Comment: I would be helpful to understand why you want this.

Comment: @JulianReschke I'm having an issue where ExtJS framework isn't working well while getting data from my API, I'm not sure, but maybe it's because the API is answering with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, so I want to try having the answer delivered without it.

Comment: The browser is removing the chunked transfer coding in XMLHttpRequest (and similar APIs), so it really should not matter.